# What are the best Javascript/Flash frameworks to render graphs or charts from data?

Tags: javascript, flash, statistics, charts, visualization

Ideally I'd like to do as little preparation data work on the server as possible. The less I have to do to prep the data from the database to make a given chart, the happier I am and the more view I can make in the time.

Some of the things I'd like to chart are, for example:

- The distribution of a series of response times
- The number of occurrences per category (basic bar chart)

I'm sure there are others I haven't thought of yet.

Anything that helps me get from a series such as:

[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 1] or more likely something like [1.2, 3.2, 3.1, 1.1, 4.3, 3.4] where it isn't just a case of counting the frequency of the item

to an actual distribution would be great.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** To clarify I guess I'm asking for more than just charting APIs, a search on Yahoo or Stack Overflow already finds answers to that. I'm looking for something that can help me turn data into visualizations with the least effort. So with the series above, something that could map it directly into some standard distributions such as a Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I like [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). It is brain-dead simple to use. You generate your data in the URL for an image, and the Google server spits back the GIF with the chart in it. You don't need JavaScript or Flash.

Comment: Plus, there are a bunch of wrappers in the language of your choice: http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/useful-links-to-api-libraries

Comment: I found JS Charts much easier to use than Google Charts, the only advanatage i felt that google charts has is that it generates images while js charts uses canvas which means they cannot be saved.

Comment: I used Google API charts and found that they are much simpler to use and render good quality graphs. However the downside is that since its a gif you cant track any mouse movements over it.

Comment: If you want to track drill-down, then no. You can track mouse movements over any GIF, rendered by Google or not.

Comment: Is there any privacy concern with Google seeing and possibly accumulating the data its provided in order to produce the chart?

Comment: `Google charts` is now the only one that is up to date with a decent documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I use [JS Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/), which is a Javascript based one, looked simple and easy enough for me to use. They even have support for xml data in addition to js. It is free and they have got some [examples](http://www.jscharts.com/examples).

Works on IE and Chrome fine, so ideally should work on Firefox. as well.

On the Flash side, there is [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) , they have got some helper classes for major languages.

**Edit:** based on the additional information in question i guess Google Visualization API (http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/) might work out for you.

Comment: I use Open Flash Chart too and really like it. Also with the open source code it is really easy to alter for application-specific features. The .NET wrapper is useful too.

Comment: The only issue with JS Charts is that you cannot do two trends in a line graph which is integral for data comparison sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)

Comment: ++ Can't beat sparklines for dashboards and info-at-a-glance scenarios. Edmund Tufte turned me onto these years ago and the release of a jQuery library has made implementation simplistic.

Answer (score 3):

I've used flot (http://code.google.com/p/flot/) with some good results. It's pure javascript, doesn't require flash. It uses an html canvas to draw the charts from javascripts. Works on msie with a plugin. Some examples: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

Comment: This is what SO uses for graphics :P

Comment: I've tested literally dozens of charting scripts, server-side and client-side (I got kinda obsessed with visualizations for a while), and flot blows all the others away, even the Google Charts API.

Comment: Yes, flot really rocks ! And my inspiration to use it comes from SO itself !!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com). It's a Flash based library. You can pass data to it in XML or CSV format (or in case you use ASP.NET there's a control wrapper which supports data-binding).

Answer (score 1):

Try the Google visualization API.

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/

Answer (score 1):

On http://www.drasticdata.nl there are some interesting flash based graph and treemap utilities.
The hierarchical bar chart or the dynamic treemap might be of interest for your task.

Answer (score 0):

I've used flotr(http://code.google.com/p/flotr/) before, which is heavily inspired by the above mentioned flot, but instead of jquery it uses prototype.  It works the same way as flot as in it is pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it extensively yet, but after some initial fiddling around i was quite impressed with [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) (which i just noticed was already mentioned by Dinesh above)

Answer (score 0):

My reports done with [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) always seem to impress.  Fairly easy to work with and lots of charting options.  Flash is the technology, so no real platform troubles for web display.

Answer (score 0):

JS Charts does not support area charts